# How can I change Git username when I want to pull or push repo?

Tags: git, macos

The default account that used to pull or push on git is not my account. Every time I do `git push`, it automatically uses the default account to do this. I searched a lot and successfully changed the username and email in `~/.gitconfig`. But it's still not woking, when I try to do push or pull, it's still not asking me to input my password and do the work using the default account which is not mine.

I'm confused about this. How can I fix this?

Comment: `~./gitconfig` is not a valid location. I assume you mean `~/.gitconfig`? Each project can have it's config at `<repo>/.git/config`. I'd check if that file exists, and you may need to change that as git starts there and works its way up the directory tree.

Comment: If that doesn't work, it may be configured to use SSH, which may be how it's authenticating. Run `git remote -v` and see if the repo link you're pushing to is via `https` or `ssh`.

Comment: I have checked '<repo>/.git/config' and it does exist and I didn't see any settings about the default account the setting is like this[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://git.kaka.io/kaka/pockettutor.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master . The pushing way is via https.

Comment: Links that start with `git` mean that it's over SSH. Check `~/.ssh/config` for a github setting.

Comment: I have done what you said.but I don't have '~/.ssh/config' and the link starts with 'https' but when I copy here,It become like this.Does this still mean it's over SSH?

Comment: I don't see a link, but rereading you post, if it's asking your for a password (as long as it's not looking for a password to the SSH key or for access to the key), it must be SSH. However, this is definitely an SSH url: `git.kaka.io/kaka/pockettutor.git`, but you may be referring to a different URL. Also, check if any folders between your repo and `~` have a `.gitconfig` file. Otherwise, I'm at a loss :)

Comment: Ok,thanks a lot.In fact,It looks like this"remote.origin.url='h't't'p's':'/'/'git.kaka.io/kaka/pockettutor.git".every time I push a change,it finished automatically.for example.My username is Jack,but after I do push.I go to git and just find the name Bob do the push except Jack(me),even I change the git config as my name and email   :(

Comment: I finally figured it out by the help of nwinkler,thanks for your attention and patience too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mac OS X (as you indicated in your question), the username/password for accessing Git repos using HTTP(S) is stored in the *Keychain Access* application.

To remove the stored username entries, open the *Keychain Access* application, then select the *login* keychain in the top left. In the bottom left part of the window, select *Passwords*. Next, type the name of your Git server in the top right *Search* box.

Once the stored entries are shown, select the ones you're interested in. Double-clicking them will open them to show details about the stored username and URL. You can also show the password from this screen.

When you have found the entries that use the wrong username, you can simply delete them. On the next push/pull, Git should ask you for your username/password, as long as the username is not part of the remote's URL.

[image: Keychain Access]

Comment: Oh!It works!!!Thank you very much!I got confused for a long time.You helped me a lot!thanks again :)

Comment: Good to hear. Just a minor comment - you might want to use the space bar after a full stop or exclamation mark - makes it easier to read :-)

Comment: Oh, and after a comma, too :-)